# Join data from one sql result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using MS SQL server 2012.

I have the following query

```
Select HedgeDate, CompanyName, HedgeValue 
FROM GasHedges
LEFT OUTER JOIN GasCompanies ON GasHedges.CompanyID = GasCompanies.ID
WHERE HedgeDate BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-05'
```

which returns

[image: SQL Table]

I want to display it in the following format.

[image: required result]

I have been working on this all morning and not really getting there.  I don't want to specify the companyName in the SQL code as more companies could get added to the table.  I have been trying different variants of joins but not getting anywhere.  I was also looking at unions but cant seem to get it.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should look at pivot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT HedgeDate, CompanyName, HedgeValue 
FROM GasHedges
LEFT OUTER JOIN GasCompanies ON GasHedges.CompanyID = GasCompanies.ID
PIVOT (count(HedgeValue) FOR CompanyName in ([RWET], [JPMorgan], [Statoil]))
WHERE HedgeDate BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-05'
```

Here you go

Edit 1,

if you want the list to be dynamic, refer [HERE](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/)
Try do it yourself to make sure you understand it

Comment: that doesn't work, just get an error on the where clause.  plus I cant specify the company name in the query

Answer (score 1):

thanks ah_hau, with your guidance I got to the following code which works

```
DECLARE @StartDate date
DECLARE @EndDate date
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(2000)
DECLARE @query nvarchar(3000)

select  @cols = coalesce(@cols + ',[' + companyName + ']', '[' + companyName + ']')
from GasCompanies
set @query = 'select *
from
(Select HedgeDate, CompanyName, HedgeValue 
FROM GasHedges
LEFT OUTER JOIN GasCompanies ON GasHedges.CompanyID = GasCompanies.ID
WHERE HedgeDate BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND dateadd(month,1+datediff(month,0,getdate()),-1)) as s
PIVOT
(
count(HedgeValue) FOR CompanyName in ( '+@cols +' )

)  as t'

execute(@query)
```